# How do I create a schedule for a query using the Redshift Query editor v2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

The query editor v2 does not seem to come with the schedule button from v1. I have followed the recommended steps to create a schedule using AWS EventBridge and have successfully attached said schedule to my redshift cluster. The schedule gets invoked but does not run the query. There is no error message logged, as far as I can tell. Does anyone have any experience with this workflow?

Answer (score 2):

**Update :** Now you can schedule queries using Query Editor V2.

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/query-editor-v2-schedule-query.html][1]

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while looking for help setting up a scheduled query in query editor V2. This functionality is now available, docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/query-editor-v2-schedule-query.html)